# Segurança de criptografia no php

Tags: php, criptografia

Sei que existem outras coisas que ajudam a manter um sistema seguro, mas gostaria de saber em específico sobre uma: a criptografia de informações.

Por exemplo, a senha é uma informação que nos meus projetos sempre tento fazer com que fique criptografada no banco. Minha dúvida é a seguinte, a criptografia que o php fornece como md5, sha1, base64_encode já são seguras por si só ou a combinação delas as torna mais forte?

Para ilustrar, o trecho abaixo:

```
$senha1 = md5($_POST['senha']);

$senha2 = sha1(md5($_POST['senha']));
```

Por algum motivo a variável `$senha2` é mais segura de usar que a variável `$senha1`?

Gostaria de saber isso, porque pretendo aplicar nos meus projetos.

Comment: MD5 e SHA1 são notavelmente inseguros se comparados à outros métodos, aconselho a dar uma olhada no **bcrypt**

Comment: Acho que a minha pergunta nesse caso se diferencia em alguns aspectos da pergunta marcada como possível duplicata. Estou sendo direto em relação a criptografia, a qual posso usar em outra situação. A pergunta relacionada pergunta sobre como fazer um sistema seguro e isso pode ir além da criptografia.

Comment: E com essa conversa de inseguros, vão acabar por dizer que são imprestáveis e não desempenham qualquer função importante, recomendo que leias [isto](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você não armazena senhas no banco de dados, ao contrário disso você armazena o hash delas, e usa isso como comparação na hora que tiver que fazer um login.

`MD5` e `SHA1` são de **mão única**, você não consegue quebrar, porém existe as tabelas prontas que possuem uma infinidade de `MD5` e seus significados, assim como `SHA1`, eu diria que `SHA1` é um pouco mais segura por ser pouca coisa mais lenta.

Para dificultar uma senha fraca ser exposta caso seu banco de dados seja vazado, utilize algum salt.

```
[salt]+[hash-da-senha]
```

> **Salt**: String aleatória gerada automaticamente e é utilizada para gerar o resultado do hash de sua senha, costuma ser gravada no banco junto ao hash gerado.

Exemplo de implementação

```
// Entrada do usuário
$input = 'minhasenha123';

// Gera o hash da senha do usuário
$hash = password_hash($input, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); 

// Hash gerado (cada vez será único)
echo $hash;

// Deve ser armazenado no banco e usado para comparação.
```

Vamos supor que o código acima produziu o seguinte resultado:

`$2y$10$OOCtogTSo0egjw1ZUHXndei8h/sZGNQh.iKBn9L2T4VbYvSGFEnP.`

A cada vez que rodar é único, porém salvamos o hash no banco, e agora vamos usa-la para comparar o login.

```
// Entrada do usuário no login
$input = 'minhasenha123';

/**
 * Código para pegar a hash do banco correspondente
 * ao usuário que tentou fazer login
 *
 * Aqui para exemplo, vamos usar a string, mas em sua aplicação
 * deve-se comparar qual usuário solicitou, se ele existe,
 * trazer a hash da senha usuário para uma variável, e compara-la
 * com o input do login
 */

$hash = '$2y$10$OOCtogTSo0egjw1ZUHXndei8h/sZGNQh.iKBn9L2T4VbYvSGFEnP.';

// Faz a verificação

if (password_verify($input, $hash))
{
    echo 'Usuário logado';
}
else
{
    echo 'Senha inválida';
}
```

Também recomendo você utilizar o `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` que é mais lento e mais robusto (sim, mais lento, é essencial diminuir propositalmente o desempenho quando o assunto é criptografia, assim seu sistema fica menos vulnerável a ataques de força bruta).

> **Nota**: A função `password_hash` está disponível nas versões 5.5 ou superiores do PHP.

Essa é a implementação mais simples e possuí bastante segurança.

Answer (score 4):

Segurança de informações é um assunto bem mais complexo do que escolher esse ou aquele modelo.

Segurança é sempre algo ligado a nós seres humanos. As senhas, por exemplo, só precisam existir para evitar que quem não é dono de tal informação possa ter livre acesso a elas.

Senhas são como fechaduras de qualquer porta. Em um ambiente seguro ou com baixo risco, não há necessidade de fechaduras complexas. Ninguém coloca fechadura na casinha do cachorro. Por outro lado, ninguém colocará um cadeado na porta de um cofre de banco.

Qualquer modelo de criptografia tem falhas. Quanto mais segura, mais custosa de se manter.

De nada adianta ter um sistema de criptografia de senha de 4096 bits se a senha trafegar aberta entre o formulário e o código de acesso.

O modelo mais básico de segurança de um sistema WEB passa principalmente pelo ponto de origem do dados. Se houver necessidade real de segurança, tem que começar pelo ambiente que deve ser SSL. Somente a partir disso é que deve se pensar em optar por esse ou aquele modelo de chave de acesso.

Para sistemas com baixo risco de vazamento de informações úteis, usar md5 ou sha1 já resolve.

Em tempo, `base64` não é hash e jamais deve ser usado como criptografia. Ele serve para transformar uma string com caracteres *nocivos* em strings com caracteres puramente ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

md5 e sha1 apesar de serem de mão única (não podem ser revertidas), existem diversas rainbow tables com várias senhas geradas com esses hashes.

Uma técnica que poderia ser aplicado seria o uso de salt, que é uma concatenação de um texto antes da sua senha, e só depois aplicado o hash, para gerar hashes diferentes dos já existentes nas rainbow tables.

O problema disso é que qualquer pessoa mal-intencionada com posso do teu salt ainda sim pode gerar uma rainbow table, por isso acredito que a forma mais segura atualmente seja utilizando salt dinâmico com algoritmos que sejam relativamente pesado para geração em massa porém rápido o suficiente para não atrapalhar o uso comum.

Hoje essas técnicas são utilizadas na função [bcrypt](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografando-senhas-no-php-usando-bcrypt-blowfish/)